# Escribir en un archivo txt

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Lo que quiero es agregar "una linea texto" cada vez que se ejecute el código.
Sin embargo lo que consigo es reemplazar todo el contenido del txt. Dejo aquí mi código.

```
const fs = require("fs");
let ruta = './log.txt'
let texto = "Esto es una prueba \n\t";
fs.open(ruta, 'w+', (err, fd) => {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }
    else {        
        fs.appendFile(ruta, texto, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            fs.close(log, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('It\'s saved!');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si miras la documentación de [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback), verás que entre [los flags que hay disponibles](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags) están:

> `'w+'` - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) **or truncated (if it exists)**.
>
> `'a'` - Open file for **appending**. The file is created if it does not exist.

Traducción:

`'w+'`: Abre en modo lectura y escritura. Crea el fichero si no existe y si existe lo trunca (borra todo su contenido).

`'a'`: Abre el fichero para añadir. Si no existe el fichero, se crea.

Por tanto tu problema es que estás borrando el contenido del fichero cada vez que lo abres, debes cambiar el flag por `'a'` (aprovecho para arreglar un par de fallos que tienes el código, mira mis comentarios:

```
const fs = require("fs");
let ruta = './log.txt'
let texto = "Esto es una prueba \n\t";
fs.open(ruta, 'a', (err, fd) => {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }
    else {
        //si tienes ya el fd (file descriptor), usémoslo        
        fs.appendFile(fd, texto, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //de nuevo, usemos el fd para cerrar el fichero abierto
            fs.close(fd, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('It\'s saved!');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

De todos modos, si sólo quieres escribir, no necesitas abrir el fichero antes, si a appendFile le pasas la ruta como string abre y cierra el fichero automáticamente, simplificando el código:

```
const fs = require("fs");
let ruta = './log.txt'
let texto = "Esto es una prueba \n\t";
fs.appendFile(ruta, texto, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Gracias! he aprendido mucho y me has ayudado con lo que necesitaba. Saludos

Comment: Si marcas la respuesta como aceptada, la pregunta quedará marcada como respondida